# Stored procudure for a search feature

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I am trying to write a stored procedure to search by DB for whatever is inserted. see below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_all_login_tb`
(
 IN p_pass varchar(100), 
 IN p_email_id varchar(100), 
 IN p_name varchar(45), 
 IN p_staff_id varchar(45), 
 IN p_status_id varchar(1) 
)
BEGIN

    set @sqlquery = 'select * from kupo_101.login_tb where login_tb.id is NOT NULL';

    IF (p_pass is not null) THEN   
        set @sqlquery = CONCAT (@sqlquery ,' AND login_tb.pass = "',p_pass,'"');
    ELSEIF (p_email_id is not null) THEN
        set @sqlquery = CONCAT (@sqlquery ,' AND login_tb.email_id = "',p_email_id,'"');
    ELSEIF (p_name is not null) THEN
        set @sqlquery = CONCAT (@sqlquery ,' AND login_tb.first_name = "',p_name,'"');
    ELSEIF (p_staff_id is not null) THEN
        set @sqlquery = CONCAT (@sqlquery ,' AND login_tb.staff_id = "',p_staff_id,'"');
    ELSEIF (p_status_id is not null) THEN
        set @sqlquery = CONCAT (@sqlquery ,' AND login_tb.status = "',p_status_id,'"');
    END IF;

    prepare stmt from @sqlquery;
    execute stmt;

END
```

```
MariaDB [kupo_101]> CALL get_all_login_tb('qewr13241wwe','','','','');
+----+--------------+------------------+----------------------+----------+--------+
| id | pass         | email_id         | first_name           | staff_id | status |
+----+--------------+------------------+----------------------+----------+--------+
|  2 | qewr13241wwe | iimama@gmail.com | Imama Igein Blessing | 10122ASD | Y      |
|  3 | qewr13241wwe | barvo@gmail.com  | ucee oluchi          | 10122AFF | N      |
+----+--------------+------------------+----------------------+----------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when use other filed to search it shows empty Set.

```
CALL get_all_login_tb('','','','10122ASD','');
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're calling the stored procedure with empty string values rather than NULL values. The IFs and ELSEIFs in the SP body are testing for NULL, not empty string.